# How to validate captcha on register page using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've tried so many tutorial about validate captcha on codeigniter with suitable for my form, but I still don't understand how to validate which when $word == $this->input->post('captcha') then would be true (validation succeded).

I've a registration controller bellow (controller/Registration.php)

```
<?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class Register extends CI_Controller {

     function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->library(array('form_validation'));
         $this->load->library('image_lib');
         $this->load->helper(array('url','form','captcha'));
         $this->load->model('m_account'); //call model
     }

     public function index() {
         $dat = array(
            'img_path' => './static/',
            'img_url' => 'http://localhost/ks/static/',
            'img_width' =>'150',
            'img_height' =>'50'
            );
         $captcha = create_captcha($dat);
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'USERNAME','required');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','EMAIL','required|valid_email');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','PASSWORD','required');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_conf','PASSWORD','required|matches[password]');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha', 'callback_validate_captcha');

         if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
             $this->load->view('reader');
             $this->load->view('account/register',$captcha);
             $this->load->view('footer');
         }else{

             $data['username'] =    $this->input->post('username');
             $data['email']  =    $this->input->post('email');
             $data['password'] =    md5($this->input->post('password'));

             $this->m_account->daftar($data);

             $pesan['message'] =    "Pendaftaran berhasil anda berhasil silahkan login";
             $this->load->view('reader');
             $this->load->view('account/sukses',$pesan);

             $this->load->view('footer');
             header( "refresh:1;url=login" );
         }
     }
    public function validate_captcha(){
    if($this->input->post('captcha') != $this->$captcha)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_captcha', 'Wrong captcha code');
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
```

This is my form registration (views/account/register.php):

```
<?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


     <div id="content">
     <h2>Pendaftaran Member Baru</h2>

     <?php echo form_open('register');?>

 <div id=form_wrapper>
 <div class=form_title>Form Pendaftaran</div>
     <div class=form_label>Username</div>
     <div class=form_value><input type="text" maxlength="15" id="user" name="username" class="form_input" autocomplete="off" width="50" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>"/> </div>
     <div class=form_label>Email:</div>
     <div class=form_value><input type="email" maxlength="100" name="email" id="email" class="form_input" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>"/></div>
     <p> <?php echo form_error('email'); ?> </p>
     <div class=form_label>Password:</div>
     <div class=form_value><input type="password" id="pass" maxlength="15" name="password" class="form_input" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>"/></div>
     <p> <?php echo form_error('password'); ?> </p>
     <div class=form_label>Password Confirm:</div>
     <div class=form_value><input type="password" id="pass" maxlength="15" name="password_conf" class="form_input" autocomplete="off"  value="<?php echo set_value('password_conf'); ?>"/></div>
     <p> <?php echo form_error('password_conf'); ?> </p>

    <p>
    <?php
echo $image;
echo $word;
?>
    <label for="name">Captcha:
      <input id="captcha" name="captcha" type="text" value=""/>
    </label></p>
     <p>
     <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Daftar" />
     </p>
 </div>
     <?php echo form_close();?>
 </div>
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this captcha. It is popular nowadays. A gift for developers from Google.

[Google reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/)

**What is reCAPTCHA?
Easy to add, advanced security**

reCAPTCHA is a free service from Google that protects your site from spam and abuse. It uses advanced risk analysis techniques to tell humans and bots apart. With the new API, a significant number of your valid human users will pass the reCAPTCHA challenge without having to solve a CAPTCHA. reCAPTCHA comes in the form of a widget that you can easily add to your blog, forum, registration form, etc. [More Info here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/)

Comment: thanks for reply my question. But i still want to use integrate captcha on codeigniter, because i'm still learning how to create registration form using codeigniter.

Comment: on captcha validation, i cant create the right code. variable $word is the captcha value. I want to make validation which is, if $this->input->post('captcha')  == $word then ......

on this function:
public function validate_captcha(){
    if($this->input->post('captcha') != $this->$captcha)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_captcha', 'Wrong captcha code');
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }